# AdSense management API testing with test account

Tags: adsense, adsense-api

I am developing a mobile application that uses AdSense management API. I am able to test it with my personal Google account linked with AdSense. However for certification purposes I need to provide a test account that could be used by third party testers.

The application itself is unusable without valid AdSense account with some sample data.

On the AdSense developer site (https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/getting_started) there is a statement indicating that there should be a possibility to create test account:

"You need an AdSense account for testing purposes. If you already have a test account, then you're all set; you can visit the AdSense user interface to set up, edit, or view your test data."

Can anyone tell me how to create test data?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this ? I am running into the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I went through this problem and solved it with the tutorial:
https://support.google.com/admob/answer/7356219?hl=en&authuser=2&ref_topic=7383088

In summary, go to: https://apps.admob.com